# Prevent API call if data present in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have 2 routes `/dashboard` and `/battery`, on `/dashboard` I call my API on `componentWillMount()`, then once I receive the response using redux I do `componentWillReceiveProps()` to update my state and its working fine, but if I navigate to /battery using react-router-dom and then want to come back to /dashboard, how can I prevent API calls because the data is already present in redux-store.

```
// To go to the /battery I do
history.push('/main/battery')

// To go to the /dashboard I do
history.push('/main/dashboard')

// Dashboard Component (/main/dashboard)
componentWillMount() {
  this._callAPI()
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // update state
}
```

Comment: Dispatch an action in your componentWillMount to Redux and in the reducer check if the right part of your state is existing. If not, call your api from the reducer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution, inside your action creator, you can get the current redux state using `getState()`. Simply check before that api call, that your redux store is empty or not set.

Here an example of an action creator that does that check:

```
requestList: () => {
        return (dispatch, getState) => {
            if (getState().list === null) {
                /* API CALL HERE*/
            }
        }
    }
```